# Need to show two label in Picker

Tags: react-native

I want to show two label values in one picker component is it possible to display I have attached a screen shot, please let me know if it is possible.[image]

Comment: what picker are you using ??, did you try {'data1\ndata2'} ??

Comment: I am using Picker of this library @react-native-picker/picker

Comment: and I have tried this {'data1\ndata2'} it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use this library : `react-native-dropdown-picker`

***Installation***

```
npm install react-native-dropdown-picker
```

here's the [documentation](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs)

i also created a snack you can check it [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@adgogo/57a779)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I can't add this {'data1\ndata2'} in this way because the data2 font style and size is different need to add one more label like sub-label, can we do that?

Comment: i updated the snack, so you can use break line with different styling

Comment: @Pooja please consider accepting the answer if it did solve your question